# how to frame a insert query with values in A cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet with values

```
 A
1000
2000
3000
4000
```

i want to frame a query like

```
insert into table_name values(a1);
insert into table_name values(a2);
insert into table_name values(a3);
```

how can i do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are probably looking for the function concatenate()
`=CONCATENATE("insert into table table_name values(",A2,");")`
here A2 is the Cell in which your value is contained.
Step 1> Goto column beside the one with values
Step 2> Apply the above formula
Step 3> Copy paste the formula for all the cells in the new column. This will take care of generating the final values.